# Repository autowired returning null

Tags: spring-data-jpa, repository, autowired

I want to make a application with Spring boot on back-end and Swing on front-end. I need to use a repository autowired on my service class, how to make it when i need to instantiate the service class?

I already tried change the repository to BeanFactory, tried to change the location of the files but i can't escape! I need to instantiate the Service class and autowired doesn't work with this.

I have a Model called Permission.
Repository (PermissionRepository.java):

```java
@Repository
public interface PermissionRepository extends JpaRepository<Permission, Long>{
    Optional<Permission> findByDescription(String description);    
}
```

Service (PermissionService.java):

```java
@Autowired
BeanFactory beanFactory;

public List<Permission> loadAll() {
 return this.beanFactory.getBean(PermissionRepository.class).findAll();
}
```

Use (BasicOperations.java):

```java
public static void initialPermission() {
 try {
    if (new PermissionService().loadAll().isEmpty()) {
    //logics
    }
  } catch(Exception e) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I expect a List, java.util.List but, the error is a nullPointer on my autowired repository
Stack:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.riTrap.service.PermissionService.loadAll(PermissionService.java:20)

Comment: you are creating a ```new PermissionService()```, you should _Autowire_ your service in ```BasicOperations``` (preferably using constructor-injection)

Comment: Right, i've done this already but, the same thing happen.
`code
public static void initialPermission() {
 try {
  if (permissionService.loadAll().isEmpty()) {
code`
Added on the top
`code
@Autowired
static PermissionService permissionService;
code`
Needed to be static because the method is static. And even if that wasn't static, i should need to initiate the BasicOperations so, not gonna work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use autowired instead of new PermissionService. You use loadAll to check if the database contains elements. If the database is big, this approach can damage your application. Suggestion : use count instead

```
@Service
public class PermissionService {

    @Autowired
    PermissionRepository permissionRepository;

    public List<Permission> loadAll() {
        return permissionRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return permissionRepository.count() == 0L;
    }
}
```

If you need to initialize the bean before usage, you can use the constructor :

```
@Service
public class BasicOperations {

    @Autowired
    public BasicOperations(PermissionService permissionService){
        if(permissionService.isEmpty()){
            //DO STUFF
        }
    }
}
```